# Child object missing in Java Rest webservice

Tags: java, rest, jaxb, jax-rs

i am trying to call the get method of the below web service

```
@Stateless
@Path("com.company.entitiesms.bom")
public class BomFacadeREST extends AbstractFacade<Bom> {

@PersistenceContext(unitName = "com.mycompany_rxws_war_1.0-SNAPSHOTPU")
private EntityManager em;

public BomFacadeREST() {
    super(Bom.class);
}
@GET
@Path("{id}")
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public Bom find(@PathParam("id") Long id) {
    return super.find(id);
}
```

where it should get all the xml elements and child elements in the entity class BOM:

```
@Entity
@Table(catalog = "MOI", schema = "dbo")
@XmlRootElement
public class Bom implements Serializable {

@Id
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Column(name = "BOM_ID", nullable = false)
private Long bomId;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "bomId")
private Collection<BOMDevices> bOMDevicesCollection;
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "bomId")
private Collection<TRInstallations> tRInstallationsCollection;
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "bomId")
private Collection<BOMATEs> bOMATEsCollection;

public Bom() {
}

public Bom(Long bomId) {
    this.bomId = bomId;
}

public Long getBomId() {
    return bomId;
}

public void setBomId(Long bomId) {
    this.bomId = bomId;
}

//@XmlTransient
public Collection<BOMATEs> getBOMATEsCollection() {
    return bOMATEsCollection;
}

public void setBOMATEsCollection(Collection<BOMATEs> bOMATEsCollection) {
    this.bOMATEsCollection = bOMATEsCollection;
}
@XmlTransient
public Collection<BOMDevices> getBOMDevicesCollection() {
    return bOMDevicesCollection;
}

public void setBOMDevicesCollection(Collection<BOMDevices> 
bOMDevicesCollection) {
    this.bOMDevicesCollection = bOMDevicesCollection;
}
```

the problem is Collection of BOMATEs is not generated in the xml output of the get method in the above web service and its class is as follow:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "BOM_ATEs", catalog = "MOI", schema = "dbo")
@XmlRootElement
public class BOMATEs implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Column(name = "ATE_ID", nullable = false)
private Long ateId;
public BOMATEs() {
}

public BOMATEs(Long ateId) {
    this.ateId = ateId;
}

public Long getAteId() {
    return ateId;
}

public void setAteId(Long ateId) {
    this.ateId = ateId;
}
@XmlTransient
public Collection<BOMDevices> getBOMDevicesCollection() {
    return bOMDevicesCollection;
}

public void setBOMDevicesCollection(Collection<BOMDevices> 
bOMDevicesCollection) {
    this.bOMDevicesCollection = bOMDevicesCollection;
}

public Bom getBomId() {
    return bomId;
}

public void setBomId(Bom bomId) {
    this.bomId = bomId;
}
}
```

i tried removing the XmlTransient annotation for the getter getBOMATEsCollection , changing the fetch type to eager with no hope

Comment: hmm, removing **@XmlTransient ** should work. can you show _result_ of your request?

Comment: actually i am receiving HTTP Status 500 - Internal Server Error without any exception thrown

Comment: is other funtions like POST,PUT working ?? if not.. look at **@Path("com.company.entitiesms.bom")** i dont think it should work .. try with **@Path("/bom")** . then set request as <BASE_PATH>/bom  eg: http://localhost:8080/bom